# How to calculate CPU Utilization in Prometheus?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, prometheus, cpu-usage

I'm new to Prometheus and I got confused about CPU usage metrics.
Here are my two cents about CPU usage. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

1. `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` =  `container_cpu_user_seconds_total` +  `container_cpu_system_seconds_total`
2. "cores" = `container_spec_cpu_quota` / `container_spec_cpu_period`
3. This is the pod used CPU time in 1 second:

   ```
   rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!=""}[1m]) by (pod, namespace)
   ```
4. This is the pod allowed CPU time in 1 second:

   ```
   (sum(container_spec_cpu_quota{image!=""}/100000) by (pod, namespace))
   ```
5. So the utilizations is like:

   ```
   rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!=""}[1m]) by (pod, namespace) / (sum(container_spec_cpu_quota{image!=""}/100000) by (pod, namespace)) *100
   ```
6. But what about those pods don't have `spec.cpu.limits`? I presume:

   ```
   rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!=""}[1m]) by (pod, namespace) / CORES_ON_NODE *100
   ```